# Need to travel a dictionary in a tree structure and explore each element

Tags: ios, json, swift, tree, reddit

I have a JSON that is returned from me from the Reddit API. This API has a recursive "replies" property. The "replies" property can have a certain number of children, and the children can have replies as well. The JSON can be found here. http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=9eddfa413472f76cca89bfda6efe3a96. Visually this looks a bit like this:

```
-Comment
   -Reply
     -Reply
       -Reply
       -Reply
       -Reply
   -Reply
-Comment
   -Reply
   -Reply
```

I'm trying to build a recursive function that will search through this dictionary, travel all nodes, and stop when all nodes have been traveled.  I have a partial function, but it only manages the first and second level of the tree (I am trying to display this data in a tableView).

```
    var numRows = 0
    for replies in children[section].data.replies {
        numRows += replies.data.replies.count
    }
    return numRows
```

Any advice on how to travel this tree?

Comment: What order do you want?  Probably a depth-first-traversal?  Try searching for that

Comment: I would like to be get information from every possible node. Will depth-first be the right solution?

Comment: As I said it depends on the order you want.  There are several ways of [traversing a tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal); all will visit each node once, but the order you retrieve the data in will vary

Comment: I guess the order doesn't necessarily matter at all. I will check the link, thank you.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the data; You probably want a pre-order traversal if you are going to display the threads the way reddit does

Comment: You might want to take a peek at https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Depth-First%20Search